# Building X server from the source

Tags: linux

I have a Virtual Box with Ubuntu running. I want to study about Xserver so I need to know how can i get the source code of the Xserver and dependent libraries on my VM so that I can build and test the Xserver with some changes.

Could someone please guide me how should I start or any link where I can get some information.

Thanks.

Comment: Good luck :-) The X source code is like a view back into history, into a time and age where OO was yet undiscovered. It's a great source of ideas and insights how to solve problems without objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download XServer source code from 
 http://www.x.org/wiki/Releases/Download?action=show&redirect=Mirrors 
When you will run the config file, all the dependencies will be automatically listed.

Comment: While configuring I am getting this error : checking for SHA1 implementation... configure: error: No suitable SHA1 implementation found. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I think they have some info here at http://lists.x.org/archives/xorg-devel/2009-October/002807.html ,Sorry for that, I cant give exact explanation as I never tried building that.

Answer (score 2):

try installing libgcrypt11-dev package first (11 may change depending on your repo)